Why are there no False Negatives in my ABC experiment simulations?
I am trying to simulate some ABC experiments to test some scenarios out. But I am finding that I am generating exactly zero false negatives.
I want to test for significance with a t-test down the line, so first I generate the base simulation parameters: a baseline conversion rate of 0.1, and a relative effect size of 5%. I chose 0.1 for my alpha, and 0.2 for my beta.
# Simulation parameters
num_repetitions = 1000
true_effect_B_prob = 0.5
true_effect_C_prob = 0.5
alpha = 0.1  # Significance level for t-tests
beta = 0.2  # Power level
CvR = 0.1  # Conversion rate
sample_variance = CvR * (1 - CvR)  # Sample variance
MDE = 0.05  # Minimum detectable effect
test_CvR = CvR + CvR * MDE
effect_size = test_CvR - CvR

analysis = TTestIndPower()
n_samples = int(np.ceil(tt_ind_solve_power(effect_size / np.sqrt(sample_variance), power=1.0-beta, nobs1=None, alpha=alpha, alternative='two-sided')))
print("Calculated sample size:", n_samples)

With these parameters, I can check that I get the required power with the following code:
es = effect_size / np.sqrt(sample_variance)
analysis = smp.TTestIndPower()
analysis.power(effect_size=es, nobs1=n_samples, alpha=0.1)

And this gives me 0.8.
The simulation is itself really simple. First I generate samples from normal distributions with the requisite parameters:
def generate_ABC_samples(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, n_samples, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob):
    samples_A = np.random.normal(CvR, sample_variance, n_samples)
    
    has_true_effect_B = np.random.rand() < true_effect_B_prob
    has_true_effect_C = np.random.rand() < true_effect_C_prob
    
    mean_B = CvR + CvR * MDE if has_true_effect_B else CvR
    mean_C = CvR + CvR * MDE if has_true_effect_C else CvR
    
    sample_variance_B = mean_B * (1.0 - mean_B)
    sample_variance_C = mean_C * (1.0 - mean_C)

    samples_B = np.random.normal(mean_B, sample_variance_B, n_samples)
    samples_C = np.random.normal(mean_C, sample_variance_C, n_samples)
    
    return samples_A, samples_B, samples_C, has_true_effect_B, has_true_effect_C

then for each repetition I calculate whether a t-test comes back significant, and whether there was a true effect (false positives and false negatives):
def simulate_ABC_experiment(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples):
    samples_A, samples_B, samples_C, has_true_effect_B, has_true_effect_C = generate_ABC_samples(
        CvR, MDE, sample_variance, n_samples, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob
    )
    
    _, p_value_B = ttest_ind(samples_A, samples_B)
    _, p_value_C = ttest_ind(samples_A, samples_C)
    
    significant_B = p_value_B < alpha
    significant_C = p_value_C < alpha
    
    results = {
        'true_positives_B': has_true_effect_B and significant_B,
        'true_positives_C': has_true_effect_C and significant_C,
        'true_negatives_B': not has_true_effect_B and not significant_B,
        'true_negatives_C': not has_true_effect_C and not significant_C,
        'false_positives_B': not has_true_effect_B and significant_B,
        'false_positives_C': not has_true_effect_C and significant_C,
        'false_negatives_B': has_true_effect_B and not significant_B,
        'false_negatives_C': has_true_effect_C and not significant_C
    }
    
    return results

Then there is some code to loop over the repetitions:
def simulate_ABC_experiments(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, num_repetitions, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples):
    summary = {
        'true_positives_B': 0,
        'true_positives_C': 0,
        'true_negatives_B': 0,
        'true_negatives_C': 0,
        'false_positives_B': 0,
        'false_positives_C': 0,
        'false_negatives_B': 0,
        'false_negatives_C': 0,
        'experiment_false_positives': 0,
        'experiment_false_negatives': 0
    }
    
    for _ in range(num_repetitions):
        results = simulate_ABC_experiment(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples)
        for key in summary:
            if key in results:
                summary[key] += results[key]

        # Experiment-level calculations
        if results['false_positives_B'] or results['false_positives_C']:
            summary['experiment_false_positives'] += 1
        if results['false_negatives_B'] or results['false_negatives_C']:
            summary['experiment_false_negatives'] += 1

    return summary


And do some bookkeeping:
results = simulate_ABC_experiments(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, num_repetitions, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples)

    # Calculate rates
    fpr_B = results['false_positives_B'] / num_repetitions
    fnr_B = results['false_negatives_B'] / num_repetitions
    fpr_C = results['false_positives_C'] / num_repetitions
    fnr_C = results['false_negatives_C'] / num_repetitions
    fpr_experiment = results['experiment_false_positives'] / num_repetitions
    fnr_experiment = results['experiment_false_negatives'] / num_repetitions

    # Create DataFrame for results
    results_data = {
        'True Positives': [results['true_positives_B'], results['true_positives_C']],
        'True Negatives': [results['true_negatives_B'], results['true_negatives_C']],
        'False Positives': [results['false_positives_B'], results['false_positives_C']],
        'False Negatives': [results['false_negatives_B'], results['false_negatives_C']],
        'False Positive Rate': [fpr_B, fpr_C, fpr_experiment],
        'False Negative Rate': [fnr_B, fnr_C, fnr_experiment]
    }

    index = ['Variation B', 'Variation C', 'Experiment']
    df_results = pd.DataFrame(results_data, index=index)

Yet, when I run the whole simulation, I consistently see zero false negatives. My intution is that I should miss ~100-200 negatives, but this isn't happening.
Why is this?

The whole simulation code is here (for easy copying):

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, norm
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower, tt_ind_solve_power
import statsmodels.stats.power as smp

np.random.seed(42)

# Function to generate samples for variations A, B, and C
def generate_ABC_samples(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, n_samples, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob):
    samples_A = np.random.normal(CvR, sample_variance, n_samples)
    
    has_true_effect_B = np.random.rand() < true_effect_B_prob
    has_true_effect_C = np.random.rand() < true_effect_C_prob
    
    mean_B = CvR + CvR * MDE if has_true_effect_B else CvR
    mean_C = CvR + CvR * MDE if has_true_effect_C else CvR
    
    sample_variance_B = mean_B * (1.0 - mean_B)
    sample_variance_C = mean_C * (1.0 - mean_C)

    samples_B = np.random.normal(mean_B, sample_variance_B, n_samples)
    samples_C = np.random.normal(mean_C, sample_variance_C, n_samples)
    
    return samples_A, samples_B, samples_C, has_true_effect_B, has_true_effect_C

# Function to simulate a single ABC experiment
def simulate_ABC_experiment(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples):
    samples_A, samples_B, samples_C, has_true_effect_B, has_true_effect_C = generate_ABC_samples(
        CvR, MDE, sample_variance, n_samples, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob
    )
    
    _, p_value_B = ttest_ind(samples_A, samples_B)
    _, p_value_C = ttest_ind(samples_A, samples_C)
    
    significant_B = p_value_B < alpha
    significant_C = p_value_C < alpha
    
    results = {
        'true_positives_B': has_true_effect_B and significant_B,
        'true_positives_C': has_true_effect_C and significant_C,
        'true_negatives_B': not has_true_effect_B and not significant_B,
        'true_negatives_C': not has_true_effect_C and not significant_C,
        'false_positives_B': not has_true_effect_B and significant_B,
        'false_positives_C': not has_true_effect_C and significant_C,
        'false_negatives_B': has_true_effect_B and not significant_B,
        'false_negatives_C': has_true_effect_C and not significant_C
    }
    
    return results

# Function to simulate multiple ABC experiments
def simulate_ABC_experiments(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, num_repetitions, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples):
    summary = {
        'true_positives_B': 0,
        'true_positives_C': 0,
        'true_negatives_B': 0,
        'true_negatives_C': 0,
        'false_positives_B': 0,
        'false_positives_C': 0,
        'false_negatives_B': 0,
        'false_negatives_C': 0,
        'experiment_false_positives': 0,
        'experiment_false_negatives': 0
    }
    
    for _ in range(num_repetitions):
        results = simulate_ABC_experiment(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples)
        for key in summary:
            if key in results:
                summary[key] += results[key]

        # Experiment-level calculations
        if results['false_positives_B'] or results['false_positives_C']:
            summary['experiment_false_positives'] += 1
        if results['false_negatives_B'] or results['false_negatives_C']:
            summary['experiment_false_negatives'] += 1

    return summary

# Example usage of the functions
if __name__ == "__main__":


    # Run simulation
    results = simulate_ABC_experiments(CvR, MDE, sample_variance, num_repetitions, true_effect_B_prob, true_effect_C_prob, alpha, n_samples)

    # Calculate rates
    fpr_B = results['false_positives_B'] / num_repetitions
    fnr_B = results['false_negatives_B'] / num_repetitions
    fpr_C = results['false_positives_C'] / num_repetitions
    fnr_C = results['false_negatives_C'] / num_repetitions
    fpr_experiment = results['experiment_false_positives'] / num_repetitions
    fnr_experiment = results['experiment_false_negatives'] / num_repetitions

    # Create DataFrame for results
    results_data = {
        'True Positives': [results['true_positives_B'], results['true_positives_C']],
        'True Negatives': [results['true_negatives_B'], results['true_negatives_C']],
        'False Positives': [results['false_positives_B'], results['false_positives_C']],
        'False Negatives': [results['false_negatives_B'], results['false_negatives_C']],
        'False Positive Rate': [fpr_B, fpr_C, fpr_experiment],
        'False Negative Rate': [fnr_B, fnr_C, fnr_experiment]
    }

    index = ['Variation B', 'Variation C', 'Experiment']
    df_results = pd.DataFrame(results_data, index=index)


I was expecting that the false negative rate of my simulations whould not be 0.0, but my intution has been uhm fooled.
